# reclaim unallocated space from SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in MS SQL server 2008. I have used `sp_spaceused` to check database size and got the following result.

[image]

So, in my DB there is 140GB unallocated space occupied by sql server. Now I want to reclaim that 140GB space for my system.

I have executed following commands to reclaim. but it doesn't work for me.

`DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (DB_Name, truncateonly)`

Its executed in 5 sec but only able to free 2MB at one time
I have tried `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (DB_Name, notruncate)` also but its executed   more then 10 hrs but didn't get any result.

Please, help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `TRUNCATEONLY` doesn't move any data. If you still have data at the end of the file that you're trying to shrink it won't shrink. `sp_spaceused` also doesn't show if it's space in your log or data file.

Comment: @JodyT, so how can I reclaim that 140GB space. currently I have data in my DB. I have tried `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (DB_Name, notruncate)` also. but it failed.

Comment: Neither of the options do what you want. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488.aspx)

Comment: @AmarjyotiChetia why do you think that would be a good idea? `reclaim ... for my system` what else is running on the DB server ? If the database really needed that space, releasing it will only cause extra delays when the database reallocates that space. You need to find out *why* that space was allocated in the first place. Was there a huge operation that generated a very large transaction log? If that was a one-off, you can shrink the transaction log file. Or is that the result of daily operations? In that case, reclaiming it will only cause the database to reallocate it.

Comment: In SSMS, right click on the database and go to Tasks > Shrink > Files to check the data and log files of the database. A lot of unused space may be normal *or* a sign of inefficient queries. Inserting 1M rows one by one generates a lot more log entries than inserting them using BULK INSERT, bcp and operations that use minimal logging. Deleting 1M rows will generate a lot more log entries than switching out a partition in a partitioned table

Answer (score 0):

TRUNCATEONLY
Releases all free space at the end of the file to the operating system. Doesn't move any pages inside the file. The data file shrinks only to the last assigned extent. Ignores target_percent if specified with TRUNCATEONLY. Azure Synapse Analytics doesn't support this option.

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE with the TRUNCATEONLY option affects the database transaction log file only. **To truncate the data file, use DBCC SHRINKFILE instead. For more information, see DBCC SHRINKFILE.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16